# Regex - replace all nulls with "", except before pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a json (not pretty formatted) where all fields with null values need to be replaced with empty string (""), except when the field names (or keys) contains the word "date" or "Date" (or "_Date").

Example (not exhaustive):

```
"Effective_Date__c":null
"Birthdate":null
```

How to do this using Java Regex?

Comment: Regex is probably the wrong tool for this.

Comment: _Please_ use a JSON parser and save yourself (and us) a big headache.

Comment: FYI, "_Date" contains "Date".

Answer (score 0):

First, I will echo the sentiment that a real JSON parser is a better idea.

Second, assuming that it's one per line as your example, you can do this by using a negative lookbehind to check that the key is not preceeded by 'date'.  Hard-coding the `:`  as a separator, replacing

```
(?<!(?:d|D)ate):null
```

with

```
:''
```

Should get you what you've asked for.

This works by searching for `:null` without `(d|D)ate` preceding it, and replacing that by the `:''` empty string you have requested.